# How to transform flat face to concave one - model palate?

Tags: modeling

I'm relative new to blender.

I'm trying to model palate in blender. So far I managed to create flat face between gingivas as in picture below:

[image]

Now I'm trying to curve it to be more realistic, result is expected as:

[image]

So far I tried with lattice, but it's giving very angular edges.

How do I bend this face to be concave?

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the ground plane (or remove it and create a new one. Then subdivide it and use *Proportional Editing* (Keyboard <kbd>O</kbd> in edit mode) to shape it to your liking.
EDIT: here the illustration: [Youtube - Blender teeth modeling](https://youtu.be/zkTb7P2HY10). It's just one way though. There might be better ways depending on the existing topology and what kind of quality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you improve your answer by illustrating how to achieve this?